# Making an animated JavaScript and WebGL gradient of approximately defined shape to achieve glowing effect

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to achieve wavy gradient effect like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yz19pwvg/13/), but with approximately defined shape and customizable color of gradients from JavaScript with the help of uniform variables which can be passed to GLSL.

[image: required appearance]

I've created a [draft of animated shape changing](https://jsfiddle.net/83efk2a7/9/), but I don't know how to implement glowing animation inside this shape.

Is it a good way to implement glowing shape changing with the help of THREE.Shape() and splineThru()? Is any better way to change shape of the same mesh instance instead recreating it like I do?

```js
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    scene.remove(object);
    object.texture?.dispose();
    object.material?.dispose();
    geometry.dispose();
    geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(getShape());
    object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(object);
    render();
}
```